# not getting hashtable value from session on other jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, hashtable

I am setting the value of a hash table in session

```
session.setAttribute("hash",chk); 
Hashtable<Integer,String> navchk = (Hashtable)session.getAttribute("hash");
Enumeration items = navchk.keys();
while(items.hasMoreElements())
{
    out.println(items.nextElement());
}
chk.clear();
```

at the particular page it is printing the values. here chk is hashtable.

on the other page when i am getting and printing values it is not working. Here is the code of second page....

```
Hashtable<Integer,String> chk1 = (Hashtable<Integer,String>)session.getAttribute("hash");

Enumeration items = chk1.keys();
while(items.hasMoreElements())
{
    out.println(items.nextElement());
}
chk1.clear();
```

Comment: Could you add the headers of the request received by these two pages. I would like to see whether these two pages receive the same JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: Why this difference in casting: `Hashtable<Integer,String> navchk = (Hashtable)session.getAttribute("hash");` and `Hashtable<Integer,String> chk1 = **(Hashtable<Integer,String>) **session.getAttribute("hash");`

Comment: Are you getting any Exception? Please provide some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one thing, you are doing,

> chk.clear();

in your first page. This will clear all your keys from that `HashTable`.
Keep in mind what you are getting from session, is a reference to the object `chk` bounded to the key 'hash'.
If you clear the keys from that object, you will not retrieve any keys in the second page.

Does that make sense ? :)

Comment: if i will not clear chk then it add more elements on every cycle. i want to copy chk on session and then send. Is their any way to do this?

Comment: @aarav What do you mean by it adds more elements ? If you want to copy in session with its values, you shouod not clear it. Or you can clone the object before callin clear and then set the cloned object in session.

Comment: Hey :) ..  i am doing ma minor project on "online test". there is "chk" (hash table) in which i am copying question number. now i am trying to pass this chk to another jsp using session object "hash" . i am fetching questions by category. once i run the project..no problem at all. but when i am going back and select another category then new values are added in chk as well as old one. but if i clear chk at end then it work properly but session problem. Hope u understand what i am trying to say or ask.